# Find the highest number from multiple columns and return a name

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I'm a complete novice at spreadsheets. I have created this spreadsheet by reading a lot of forums and muddling together formulas. I have now hit a problem that I can neither fix nor find out how to fix so I am hoping someone here can help! I have posted the link to my spreadsheet below and is editable.

[image]

What I want to do is find the highest 'OL' (offence level) and return the name of the player in a box underneath the their highest OL. The formula I have in R5 returns a name, but only for one column. What I need is for the formula to look at multiple columns (edit -**(every column that has OL above it)**) and tell me who has the top OL.

edit - **I'm not sure what I want it to do in the event of a tie. Alphabetical maybe.**

edit - **The reason I use 'large' is beyond me, sorry. I literally searched the internet for something that would work and that's the closest I got. I was hoping to just add more columns into the formula, but it doesn't like that for some reason**

Hopefully this is enough to be getting on with? Let me know if any more info is needed.

Comment: " look at multiple columns " - which columns?  In your R5 formula, what is row(A1) supposed to do (why not code the value 1)?  What should the answer be?

Comment: How is it supposed to work in the event of a tie?

Comment: You search all of the OL columns to find the max value that goes in R3.  Why do you use a different function (Large), and search only column I for the name that goes under it?  Why not use R3 for your name search?

Comment: @Malhat Don't make us go to another site to look up data. That data could disappear. Also, it is one extra action to take: some readers just will not bother, so *you* will get less people to look at your problem. I have inserted a screenshot instead of the external link to Google.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, got an answer for this now!

```
=join(", ",filter(A11:A,len(transpose(trim(query(transpose(if(filter(I11:AC,I10:AC10="OL")=max(filter(I11:AC,I10:AC10="OL")),"#",)),"select*",99))))))
```

Thanks for your help though :)